# Is there any Block diagram of BCM2837 showing GPU and CPU interface?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I was referring to the raspberry pi (I have raspberry Pi 3 Model B) boot process, where the second stage bootloader is executed on RISC core of the GPU while the CPU is still powered off.
I would like to understand more on this process, as the GPU block is integral part of the BCM2837 itself.

I referred BCM2835 user manual and ARM Cortex-A53's TRM as well, but no where a clear picture or block diagram available showing the interface between CPU and GPU.

Are there any documents for this?